# Dynamically calling gather function in MatLab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to dynamically call the `gather()` function in MatLab.

I am currently doing something like so:

```
for index_1 = 1:1:document_count
  current_filename = "random_file"+index_1+".mat";
  data = load(current_filename);
  pci= gather(datasets.current_filename.pci.dist);
end
```

In the above, the data is loaded however the gather function fails, I assume because I am passing it a String in the middle. I am not sure what a workaround could be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the string (current_filename) in parenthesis when using it as a field name of a `struct`.  See [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html).

```
for index_1 = 1:1:document_count
   current_filename = "random_file"+index_1+".mat";
   data = load(current_filename);
   pci= gather(datasets.(current_filename).pci.dist);
 end
```

That said, I am guessing you will need to drop the extension (.mat) off of your filename for this to work.  For example, do you really have `datasets.random_file1.mat.pci.dist`?

Answer (score 0):

The way in which I did it was:

```
fields = fieldname(data)
data = getfield(data,fields{1})
```

I used this technique to iterate through the subfields

```
pci_field = getfield(data, fields{1})
pci = gather(pci_field.dist)
```